# Why comparing two strings as object causes unexpected result

Tags: c#, inheritance, equals, equality

Consider the following piece of code.

```
object str = new string(new char[] { 't', 'e', 's', 't' });
object str1 = new string(new char[] { 't', 'e', 's', 't' });
Console.WriteLine(str==str1); // false
Console.WriteLine(str.Equals(str1));  // true
```

I understand the equality operator working here that as we have implicitly casted to object, the equality operator is checking the references of both if they are equal and returns false.

But i am confused on the second one, returning true looks like it is calling Equals override implementation provided by the String type and it checks for content of string if they are equal.

My question is why it doesn't check for content equality for operator as well, their actual type is string not object. right ?

while the follwing code outputs ture for both:

```
object str = "test";
object str1 = "test";
Console.WriteLine(str==str1); // true
Console.WriteLine(str.Equals(str1)); // true
```

Comment: Calls to functions or variables are always as close as possible to the actual class of an object. The call to `Equals` thus calls `string.Equals` which is defined to compare the contents of the string, rather than the default `object.Equals`.
If you absolutely want to use the `Equals` of `object`, you can use `(str as object)?.Equals(str1 as object)`.

Comment: @khlr You should add that as an answer, the currently existing ones are kind of missing the point of **why** it is happening

Comment: But it's wrong - strings are NOT VALUE TYPES.

Comment: @khlr `string` is not a real value type; it is an immutable reference type which overrides `Equals` and has a C# pre-defined overload of `operator ==`. Edit: Matthew beat me to it.

Comment: @Jeppe ah, sure, you're right!

Comment: @HenkHolterman can you elaborate more what you said?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With:

```
Console.WriteLine(str==str1); // false
```

it is determined *at compile-time* which C# pre-defined (formal) overload of `operator ==` to use. Since `str` and `str1` are *declared* as `object`, the overload `operator ==(object, object)` is chosen. This is fixed at compile-time. Just because the actual run-time types happen to be more specific, that does not change. If you want binding at run-time, use `Console.WriteLine((dynamic)str == (dynamic)str1); /* true */` instead.

With:

```
Console.WriteLine(str.Equals(str1));  // true
```

you call a ***virtual*** method on `object`. Virtual means it will go to whatever `override` is relevant at run-time. The class `System.String` has an override, and since `str` will have run-time type `System.String`, the override will be used by the "virtual dispatch".

---

Regarding the addition to the bottom of your question: That situation is different because of *string interning*. String interning is an optimization where the same physical instance is used for formally distinct strings whose values are identical. When you have two strings whose values are given in the source code, string interning will "optimize" and make two references to the *same* instance. This is usually harmless because strings are guaranteed to be *immutable*. So normally you do not care if it is the same instance or another instance with identical value. But in your example, we can "reveal" the interning.

Note: String interning was not relevant to your original question. Only after you added a new example to your question, string interning became relevant.

Comment: Wow, that seems like a horrible mistake for an OO language. Seriously, the method called should not be a base class method just because you've declared the object as an instance of the base class. Gross.

Comment: Why the closing comment that another answer was temporarily wrong between edits?  It doesn't make your answer better.

Comment: @SethBattin You are right. I deleted the mention of other answers. I still have a note that string interning matters for the last part but not for the first one.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you're missing what's going on. The compiler has determined that `operator ==(object, object)` is the most appropriate match. It definitely isn't going to pass an `object` into a `string` expecting method!

Answer (score 3):

When == is used on an expression of type object, it'll resolve to System.Object.ReferenceEquals.

Equals is just a virtual method and behaves as such, so the overridden version will be used (which, for string type compares the contents).

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of **string interning**; when you write:

```
object str = "test";
object str1 = "test";
Console.WriteLine(str==str1);
```

This works as expected as the two strings are internally and silently copied to one location by the compiler so the two pointers will actually point to the **same object**.

If you create a string from an array of chars, the compiler is not clever enough to understand your intention and that it is the equivalent of above, so, being a string a *reference type*, they're effectively two different *objects in memory*.

Have a look at this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/

The **Equals** method is overridden in string, therefore it's comparing the actual content of the string rather than the address as **==** (**ReferenceEquals**) does in your case as the type is **object**.

Comment: @HenkHolterman if you read my whole answer you would have seen that it's written there.

Comment: I was referring to the first part as people expect strings to be equal to another string just because they have the same characters when they are reference types. "This happens" means that the **true** value of the comparison happen only for interning.

Comment: The answer is not stating: this always happens, maybe writing "sometimes" would have saved myself this useless endless discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because the `String` `==` [operator](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,661) only takes `string` types as parameters, while the `.Equals` [method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,592) takes `object` types as parameters.

Since the string `==` only take `string` types as parameters, the overload resolution selects the object `==` operator to use for the comparison.

Answer (score -4):

The help to `String.Equals` method is giving this as a remark:

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and
>   culture-insensitive) comparison.

So, the comparison is done by checking the string char by char, thus giving true.

Comment: @GrantWinney Since `Equals` is a virtual method and `String` has an override for `Equals`, `String.Equals` is the one that ends up being called. The `==` however, is the `Object` version.